# Can run 4k60fps but not 1080p 60fps

Tags: hardware, graphics-card

I started one of my games and noticed it was a bit choppy.. the game looked a bit too good to be true so I checked the settings and it was running in 4k. I run all my games in 1080p because 4k on max settings usually gets around 35-40fps. I noticed my desktop resolution was also set to 4k. I went into the settings and changed my resolution to 1080p, but when I changed it to 1080p, the FPS was capped to 30 and I couldn't change it. I changed it to 4k and I could run it on 60fps. But not 1080p somehow. I thought maybe its because I was trying out DSR a few days ago, but I went into the Nvidia control panel and reset it. No effect. still capped at 30FPS. I'm on a GTX1660 SUPER, and using a 4k TV. All my drivers are up to date according to GForce Experience. I just got this PC and everything is brand new.

Windows itself caps to 30 FPS, not just games.
I just want to run windows in 1080p60FPS

Comment: FPS caps may be game-specific. What game are you experiencing this with?

Comment: This is a detailed explanation, but you haven't identified clearly the problem you want us to solve. Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted NVidia live support and the agent told me to use their cleanup tool to uninstall the drivers then reinstall them. It solved the issue.
Solution for people who visit the forum 5 years later having the same issue: Reinstall your drivers.